# React Context not working with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to get react context working with SSR. This is what I have

```
// server/index.s

import express from "express";
import serverRenderer from "./middleware/renderer";
const PORT = 3000;
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.use("^/$", serverRenderer);

app.use(router);
app.listen(PORT, error => {
  console.log("listening on 3000 from the server");
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

This is what the renderer looks like-

```
export default (req, res, next) => {
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "..", "index.html");
  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, htmlData) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      return res.status(404).end();
    }
    const store = configureStore();
    store.dispatch(getDesktopFooter(`${req.url}`)).then(data => {
      const preloadedState = store.getState();
      const TestContext = React.createContext({
        hello: "hello"
      });
      const renderedBody = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
        <TestContext.Provider value={{ hello: "hello" }}>
          <DummyApp />
        </TestContext.Provider>
      );

      // const renderedBody = "";
      //render the app as a string
      const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

      //inject the rendered app into our html and send it
      // Form the final HTML response
      const html = prepHTML(htmlData, {
        html: helmet.htmlAttributes.toString(),
        head:
          helmet.title.toString() +
          helmet.meta.toString() +
          helmet.link.toString(),
        body: renderedBody,
        preloadedState: preloadedState
      });

      // Up, up, and away...
      return res.send(html);
    });
  });
};
```

My DummyApp looks like

```
import React from "react";
import Test from "./Test";
import { default as AppStyles } from "./App.css";
export default class DummyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("DUMMY APP CONTEXT");
    console.log(this.context);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={AppStyles.base}>
          <Test />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The context is always `{}`, when it should be `{hello: "hello"}`

Why is this happening?

Comment: You don't seem to have a context [`Consumer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) in your `DummyApp`.

Comment: But the docs say I don't need one?https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context

Comment: That example you linked is setting the `contextType` of the component, which you are not doing either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consume the context in your component for it to be able to read it.

You also need to create the `TestContext` outside of the server render function so that your component can import it and consume it.

**Example**

```
// TestContext.js
export default TestContext = React.createContext({
  hello: "hello"
});

// server.js
const TestContext = require("./TestContext.js")

export default (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  const renderedBody = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <TestContext.Provider value={{ hello: "hello" }}>
      <DummyApp />
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
  // ...
};

// DummyApp.js
import TestContext from "./TestContext.js";

export default class DummyApp extends React.Component {
  static contextType = TestContext;

  render() {
    console.log(this.context);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={AppStyles.base}>
          <Test />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So @Tholle was technically correct, but there was another issue that was the real problem. There wasn't much out there on this, so if someone faces the same problem, I hope they read this answer.

`contextType` only works for when the react version is >= `16.6.0`.

This isn't mentioned in the react docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype, but weirdly is mentioned here

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-react-166